# Angular displaying data in table from json

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am working probably on a addon for a Minecraft plugin.

Now i was finishing to write the services but i dont have any clue how to display this bunch of data in a table sorted after the interface i was writing for it.

Sourcecode of my Project: https://github.com/LarsE343/AdvancedBan-Webinterface

```html
{
  "punishments": [
    {
      "calculation": null, 
      "end": "-1", 
      "id": 2, 
      "name": "partygirl3", 
      "operator": "Nintendonator_xp", 
      "punishmentType": "WARNING", 
      "reason": "test", 
      "start": "1520165103063", 
      "uuid": "d2ed075762504663bb67a73155d69269"
    }, 
    {
      "calculation": null, 
      "end": "1520196276893", 
      "id": 4, 
      "name": "partygirl3", 
      "operator": "Nintendonator_xp", 
      "punishmentType": "TEMP_MUTE", 
      "reason": "none", 
      "start": "1520178276926", 
      "uuid": "d2ed075762504663bb67a73155d69269"
    }, 
    {
      "calculation": null, 
      "end": "-1", 
      "id": 5, 
      "name": "tosh94", 
      "operator": "Nintendonator_xp", 
      "punishmentType": "WARNING", 
      "reason": "test", 
      "start": "1520180242009", 
      "uuid": "tosh94"
    }, 
    {
      "calculation": null, 
      "end": "-1", 
      "id": 6, 
      "name": "tosh94", 
      "operator": "Nintendonator_xp", 
      "punishmentType": "WARNING", 
      "reason": "test", 
      "start": "1520180567341", 
      "uuid": "tosh94"
    }, 
    {
      "calculation": null, 
      "end": "-1", 
      "id": 7, 
      "name": "tosh94", 
      "operator": "Nintendonator_xp", 
      "punishmentType": "BAN", 
      "reason": "test", 
      "start": "1520180606379", 
      "uuid": "tosh94"
    }, 
    {
      "calculation": null, 
      "end": "-1", 
      "id": 8, 
      "name": "partygirl3", 
      "operator": "Nintendonator_xp", 
      "punishmentType": "WARNING", 
      "reason": "Bitte \u00fcberdenke dein Verhalten", 
      "start": "1520181381607", 
      "uuid": "d2ed075762504663bb67a73155d69269"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to sort it like in the table formated:

```html
<style>
  #customers {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #customers td, #customers th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
  }

  #customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

  #customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

  #customers th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
  }
  .text-center {
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
<div class="text-center">
  <h1>Willkommen,</h1>
  <br>
  <p>Du bist also auf der Suche nach einem historischem Verbrechen?</p>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
<table id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Grund</th>
    <th>Teammitglied</th>
    <th>Art der Strafe</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let punishments of _postsArray">
    <td>{{punishments.id}}</td>
    <td>{{punishments.name}}</td>
    <td>{{punishments.reason}}</td>
    <td>{{punishments.operator}}</td>
    <td>{{punishments.punishmentType}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Lars, Arrays have a sort()-method. You can write your own comparators and use them inside sort(). In your case, as you are using unique id's as first sort-criteria, it would be sufficient to implement just one comparator, though.

Comment: Hey, the data is at the moment not displayed in any table because i cant take the data and put them in using *ngfor and thast why i am asking for support / a idea how to do that and sorting stuff you aint having in the moment wont help me. i am a newbie to angular and i have no plan how to sort stuff in.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to use ngx-datatable.

I will post you the link to the Demos. (It futhermore offers sorting and so on)

http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/

[EDIT]

Example of default sorting with ngx-datatable:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'default-sorting-demo',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h3>
        Client-side Sorting
        <small>
          <a href="https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/demo/sorting/sorting-default.component.ts" target="_blank">
            Source
          </a>
        </small>
      </h3>
      <ngx-datatable
        class="material"
        [rows]="rows"
        [columnMode]="'force'"
        [headerHeight]="50"
        [footerHeight]="50"
        [rowHeight]="50"
        [scrollbarV]="true"
        [sorts]="[{prop: 'name', dir: 'desc'}]">
        <ngx-datatable-column name="Company">
          <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
            {{row.company}}
          </ng-template>
        </ngx-datatable-column>
        <ngx-datatable-column name="Name">
          <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
            {{row.name}}
          </ng-template>
        </ngx-datatable-column>
        <ngx-datatable-column name="Gender">
        </ngx-datatable-column>
      </ngx-datatable>
    </div>
  `
})
export class DefaultSortingComponent implements OnInit {

  rows = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetch((data) => {
      this.rows = data;
    });
  }

  fetch(cb) {
    const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', `assets/data/company.json`);

    req.onload = () => {
      const data = JSON.parse(req.response);
      cb(data);
    };

    req.send();
  }

}
```

Comment: ty, i will try it with that :D

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19226061)

Comment: @KobyDouek you are right, but ngx-datatable is a big topic and it depends on the user, which solution/parts he really needs.

Comment: now please write a tutorial how to install that shit because i am unable to import the default npm package, i am just getting the message that the package isnt found

Comment: What did not work? Have you installed ngx-datatable via npm? Command: `npm install @swimlane/ngx-datatable --save`

Comment: it isnt working on angular5 just getting huge stacktraces for nothing but no data, did you have a better idea?  I was trying it with https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started  but now i am getting the error : InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'      in the tabletag i am using *ngFor="let punishments of _postsArray | async

Comment: hii lars _The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted._ Is postsArray an array of observables? Because you are using the async pipe